# Can a volcano perpetually spew ash without massive-scale eruptions?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

This volcano is such that it never explodes at a scale large enough to cause destruction further than its own top slopes (it is a veeeeeeeeeery high mountain, for mythology reasons). Does it make scientific sense, even when it's not erupting, to have it perpetually spew quantities of ash into the atmosphere from where they'd fall on to the nearby agricultural belt? (for soil fertility and magic plants reasons).

Think something like the ashfalls from [Mistborn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistborn), only that the particles are much smaller and generally not noticeable except a few kilometres from the mountain's base.

Would this make scientific sense or do I need to apply handwavium?

Comment: If material comes out of the volcano, that is called an eruption. Go through the [types of volcanic eruptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_volcanic_eruptions) and pick one which suits best. Maybe a [Strombolian eruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strombolian_eruption) (the volcano Stromboli in Italy "has been in almost continuous eruption for the past 2,000–5,000 years", so it may fit); or maybe a [Vulcanian eruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcanian_eruption).

Comment: There are a series of Geologic Hot Spots where there is considerable volcanic activity unrelated to any techtonic plate bounderies.  Hawaii and Yellowstone are both examples of these, with the former being the most active volcano in the world.

Comment: Define perpetual, Stromboli. erupted every minute or so for several decades.

Comment: @Ribhu Hooja, when I saw your title I was thinking Mistborn as well...